# Install pdf2swf on Ubuntu Trusty Tahr(14.04)

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, packaging

It seems the Ubuntu 14.04 repository contains a version of swftools without pdf2swf--see https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/swftools

> This package does not include pdf2swf and avi2swf

How do I get pdf2swf installed on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: so who is the coward who downvoted me without commenting why?

Comment: +1 I've been looking for this for a long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing an older version of swftools which supports pdf2swf. For example .8.1-1
This version contains pdf2swf but check if it is compatible with ubuntu 14.04.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/hardy/+package/swftools

Answer (score 4):

This will install pdf2swf on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
# See: http://fcorti.com/2014/10/13/how-to-install-alfresco-5-0-ubuntu-14-04-lts/
sudo apt-get -y install libjpeg62 libgif4
sudo apt-get -y install libart-2.0-2
wget -P /tmp/ http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/pool/partner/s/swftools/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
chmod a+x /tmp/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i /tmp/swftools_0.9.0-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

It will then be available at `/usr/bin/pdf2swf`.

---

*Earlier attempt - **does not work** properly:*

Thanks to the comment by @user229534 above, I managed to install pdf2swf on Ubuntu 14.04 using:

```
apt-get -y install libart-2.0-2 libjpeg62 libt1-5       # Manually-resolve dependencies for swftools_0.8.1
wget -P /tmp/ http://launchpadlibrarian.net/11111323/swftools_0.8.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
dpkg -i /tmp/swftools_0.8.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
rm /tmp/swftools_0.8.1-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

However, this method gives errors 'rfxswf: Warning: num_bits overflow in swf_SetRect' when converting some PDFs. So use the first method above instead.

Comment: Thank-you! Needed this on 16.04 for a legacy project. Compiling from source was not working. Above works great!